# add_image_size for header_image

Tags: php, images, headers

How can I add image size for header_image() just like featured image by using add_image_size()

What is the correct way of adding image size for header_image()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may can help you

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ,'promotions', 
    'services', 'counter') );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200, true );
add_image_size( 'slider-image', true );
```

Image will resize according to your html code

Comment: I cannot understand

Comment: this is for theme support, array is defined for post type and in add_image_size slider_image is for id